# ref undefined within a modal component material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-ref

How can I prevent `canvasRef.current` from being undefined here? It seems the modal component from material ui is causing problems with the canvas ref. How can I prevent this from happening? I tried the ref callback by setting `canvasRef.current` to the node value, but still no luck.

```
const Child = (props) => {

  const canvasRef = useRef();

  const handleViewStuff = useCallback(() => {
     
    apiCall(id)
      .then((response) => {
        
        // do stuff

        return stuff;
      })
      .then((result) => {

        result.getPage().then((page) => {
        
          const canvas = canvasRef.current; // canvas.current is undefined here
          const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

          canvas.height = 650;
          

          const renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
           
          };
    
          page.render(renderContext);
        
        });
      });

  }, []);

  return (
<>

  <Modal>

    <canvas ref={(e) => {canvasRef.current = e}} />

  </Modal>

  <button onClick={handleViewStuff}>View stuff</button>

</>
```

Comment: Hi, have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to assign `ref` to a DOM element with `useRef` is

```html
<canvas ref={canvasRef} />
```

docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-cori-dj5nk?file=/src/App.js